# Plotting a point (4x1) matrix in 3d Plot on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, point

How can I plot the New_P in 3D
I'm using robotic toolbox peter corke
I should use trplot() function but it's not working
it shows that it takes 3x3 or 4x4
any way to plot it on 3d

```
 P = transpose([2,3,4,0]);
 New_P = trotx(45) * P
trplot(New_P)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read on [`trplot`](http://www.petercorke.com/RTB/r9/html/trplot.html), it says that:

> `trplot(T, options)` draws a 3D coordinate frame represented by the
> homogeneous transform `T` **(4x4)**.

and

> `trplot(R, options)` as above but the coordinate frame is rotated
> about the origin according to the orthonormal rotation matrix `R`
> **(3x3)**.

I do not know how `trtox` is defined and what the class of `trtox(45)` is, but `P` is a 4x1 vector and therefor `New_P` most likely does not seem to be a proper input for `trplot`, hence the complaint on the input size.